# How do I setup my own time zone in Django?

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-settings

I live in Chittagong, Bangladesh and my time zone is GMT+6. How can i change to this time zone in Django settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the timezone as `'Asia/Dhaka'` in the [**`TIME_ZONE`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE):

```
# settings.py

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'
# …
```

Note that if [**`USE_TZ`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) is set to `True`, then:

> When `USE_TZ` is `True`, this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own time zone in setting.py, `USE_TZ = True` `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'`.
[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE)